# how does quantile function works in pandas

Tags: pandas, series, quantile

I am using pandas to calculate quantile value of a Series

```
s = pd.Series([2,4,5,8,10,12,15,19])
print(s.quantile(0.25))
```

Per my understanding, to calculate the 0.25 quantile, the formular is:

```
pos = (8+1)*0.25 = 2.25
```

now I can find two explanation of this pos value:
explanation A: the pos indicate the quantile value should be closer to the 2nd number, then the quantile value should be:

```
q_value = 4 + (5 - 4) * 0.25 = 4.25
```

explanation B: the fractional part indicate 25% of the quantile should come from the 2nd number and 75% from the 3rd number, then the quantile value should be:

```
q_value = 4 * 0.25 + 5 * 0.75 = 4.75
```

When the run the code, the result is 4.75, seems pandas get the quantile value based on explanation B.
But when I change the code to

```
print(s.quantile(0.3))
```

the return value is 5.3, none of the explanations can get this return value, I am a bit confusing now, can someone help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html), the default method used for interpolation is `linear`:

> linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.

We first need to find out how `index` is calculated (and then get its fractional part):

```
index = distance_between_first_and_last_element * q
```

So, in your example, we'd have a distance of 7 (because 2 and 19 are 7 positions apart). This leads to:

```
 index = 7 * 0.3 = 2.1
```

Of course, we need to keep only the **fractional** part of it, which is simply `0.1`, so `fraction` is equal to `0.1`.

Moreover, the `0.3` quantile that you've asked for is between 5 and 8 (which are numbers in your list), so these will stand for `i` and `j` respectively.

Why? Because your index is `2.1`, which is between `2` and `3`, so:

```
i = s[2] # which is equal to 5 in your Series
j = s[3] # which is equal to 8 in your Series
```

All these lead to:

```
5 + (8-5) * 0.1
```

which equals to:

```
5.3
```

---

According to the same logic, we can calculate the `0.25` percentile:

```
index = 7 * 0.25 # 1.75
fraction = 0.75 # the fractional part of index
i = s[1] # 4
j = s[2] # 5
answer = 4 + (5-4) * 0.75 -> 4.75
```